# how to integrate catalog of products in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm integrating html to wordpress, but I can't solve how to integrate a catalog of products. There are some blocks, if you click on one it opens a main page with description of this product but some blocks have subcatalog and I don't know what to do with them, I would appreciate if you help me. This is the only code on the page which generates blocks from wordpress admin panel.

HTML

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : query_posts('cat=10');   
while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
?> 
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="news-block">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="news-img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
            <div class="news-lens"></div>
            <div class="news-date"><?php the_time('d.m.y'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="news-content">
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<? endwhile;  
endif;
wp_reset_query();                 
?>
```